# how to get such an item in css

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<div class="content">
   <% if (info || continuedInfo ) { %>
     <span class="info"><%= info %></span>
     <span class="counter">3</span>
     <span><%= continuedInfo %></span>
   <% } %>
 </div>
```

info and continuedInfo is 2x textarea and if you type something there it is displayed to the user. The problem is that if the person who fills in the textarea will do an enter at the info at the end of the sentence it is not parallel align there is a space by nbsp and it looks like this
https://zapodaj.net/f9648c037bccb.png.html

this is what it looks like on the website:
https://zapodaj.net/f8fb8a67490c2.png.html?fbclid=IwAR309pjL1LgRBMox4RCrlJ7N6fy6R4CDU5s4-iSAychwmxBdJi58xKW0ZyA

I tried to catch it in css but it doesn't work: P

```
.info:contains('&nbsp;') {
  display: none;
 }
```

Comment: Please make a jsfiddle for this

Comment: Not possible in CSS. Can you do something like `<%= info.trim() %>` instead?